# Is it possible to compare two seperate instances of objects that are considered callbacks using the equals() method?

Tags: java, interface, callback, compare

I have two seperate objects that are from the same class, and using them as callbacks.

I would like to compare them at runtime in my app, because I'm relying on the equals method in some collection to make the comparison possible.

The thing is, you can't rely on any fields cause there is just not any.

Sample:

```java
interface Action {
    void apply();
}
```

```java
class ActionImpl implements Action {

    @Override
    public void apply() {
        System.out.println("Hi from" + this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        // What to compare?
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main() {
    Action action1 = new ActionImpl();

    Action action2 = new ActionImpl();

    System.out.println(action1.equals(action2)); // Wanting the output to be true
}
```

Any way possible to be able make the comprison?

Comment: These things are stateless. You can either rely on default equality (reference equality, i.e. same instance), or you can say that all instances are the same, i.e. `return obj instanceof ActionImpl`. Other than those 2, there is nothing to compare.

Comment: I feel like checking for the type as you suggested would be a good option. I actually feel like this would be a solution for my use case. I would love to mark this as an accepted answer if it actually was an answer.